# Solving $x+(x+a)^2=b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I stumbeled upon an equation of the form: $$x+(x+a)^2=b$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to solve for $x$, but I don't know how? I want to arrive at some expression on the form $x=u$, where $u$ is a function of $a$ and $b$. Here is what I tried:

$$x+x^2+2xa+a^2=b \Rightarrow x(x+1+2a)=b-a^2 \Rightarrow ?$$

$$x+e^{\ln{(x+a)^2}}=b \Rightarrow x+e^{2\ln{(x+a)}}=b \Rightarrow ?$$

$$x^2+x(1+2a)+a^2=b \Rightarrow \sum_{j=0}^2 k_j x^j =b \Rightarrow ?$$

I just can't think of a procedure to solve this kind of expression. How do you solve expressions of this kind, where you have some power plus some lower power. In  general I want to know the procedure to solve this kind of expression:

$$x^p+(x+a)^q=b, \qquad q>p \quad p,q\in \mathbb{N}$$

or equivalently:

$$\sum_{j=0}^qk_jx^j=b, \qquad \text{ where }k_j \text{ are similar (but different) to the coefficients of } (x+a)^q$$

---

Also: feel free to edit the tags so they are appropriate.

Comment: If you expand $(x+a)^2$, you have a quadratic equation !

Comment: Yes, thank you! I also discussed it with a friend that pointed it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just expand it and solve it as a quadratic equation:

$$x+(x+a)^2=x+x^2+2xa+a^2=x^2+(2a+1)x+a^2=b \Rightarrow x^2+(2a+1)x+(a^2-b)=0$$

This is on the form $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$ and in this case $A=1,B=(2a+1)$ and $C=(a^2-b)$. Using these values we get:

$$x=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B-4AC}}{2A}=\frac{-(2a+1)\pm\sqrt{(2a+1)-4(a^2-b)}}{2}$$

$$x=\frac{-2a-1\pm\sqrt{-4a^2+2a-4b+1)}}{2}=-a-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{-a^2+\frac{1}{2}a-b+\frac{1}{4}}$$

In the general case of $\sum_{j=0}^{q}k_jx^j=b$, we just move the $b$ to the other side and absorb it in $k_0=a^q-b$, so that we get

$$\sum_{j=0}^q k_jx^j=0$$

which we can use various methods to solve.